# Why can my Docker app receive UDP data without publishing the port?

Tags: docker, sockets, networking, tcp, udp

I'm learning Docker networking. I'm using Docker Desktop on Windows.

I'm trying to understand the following observations:

Short version in a picture:

[image]

Longer version:

**First setup (data from container to host)**

- I have a simple app running in a *container*. It sends one UDP-datagram to a specific port on the host (using `"host.docker.internal"`)
- I have a corresponding app running on the *host*. It listens to the port and is supposed to receive the UDP-datagram.

That works without publishing any ports in docker (expected behavior!).

**Second setup (data from host to container)**

- I have a simple app on the *host*. It sends one UDP-datagram to a specific port on the loopback network (using `"localhost"`)
- I have a corresponding app running in a *container*. It listens to the port and is supposed to receives the UDP-datagram.

That works only if the container is run with option `-p port:port/udp` (expected behavior!).

**Third setup (combination of the other two)**

- I have an app "Requestor" running in a *container*. It sends a UDP request-message to a specific port on the host and then wants to receive a response-message.
- I have a corresponding app "Responder" running on the *host*. It listens to the port and is supposed to receive the request-message. Then it sends a UDP response-message to the endpoint of the request-message.

This works as well, and - that's what I don't understand - without publishing the port for the response-message!

How does this work? I'm pretty sure there's some basic networking-knowledge that I simply don't have already to explain this. I would be pleased to learn some background on this.

Sidenote:

Since I can do `curl www.google.com` successfully from inside a container, I realize that a container definitely must not publish ports to receive any data. But there's TCP involved here to establish a connection. UDP on the other hand is "connectionless", so that can't be the (whole) explanation.

Comment: NAT has to work for UDP as well. It does basically the same thing it does for TCP.

Comment: But I don't think there's a NAT involved, anyway. Doesn't your docker container have an IP address, can't the host directly communicate with that address?

Comment: @user253751 As far as I have read, there is a NAT involved. And YES, the container has an IP, but I cannot communicate with that just like that, at least with Docker-Desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation, **NAT** seems to be the answer.

According to [these explanations](https://argus-sec.com/docker-networking-behind-the-scenes/), a NAT is involved between the *loopback* interface and the *docker0* bridge.

This is less recognizable with Docker Desktop for Windows because of the following ([source](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/networking/)):

> Because of the way networking is implemented in Docker Desktop for Windows, you cannot see a docker0 interface on the host. This interface is actually within the virtual machine.